# Help me understand how CentOS Stream fits in the space between Fedora and RHEL

Tags: centos, fedora, distributions

I am looking to redo my home(ish) server. I was running FreeBSD but have decided to jump back to Linux for several reasons out of the scope of this.

I want to still run OpenZFS as that is what is running now on FreeBSD. However this where I can to a crossroad. While for the most part Fedora is capable of running ZFS (pending the kernel is at the right version) but the speed at which the kernel updates is not ideal of this situation which could lead to my machine becoming unbootable. My next choice was to run CentOS Stream since its a bit more stable in versioning to Fedora but not quite as stable as RHEL.

Where I am having a little bit of trouble is right here, I understand where in a development model CentOS Stream fits. However, I don't understand is where it's suitable for use. Would it be appropriate to say it's for Dev and QA servers?

My goal is basically looking for something that feels like an slower moving Fedora but with all the cool features. I am pretty sure if I went AlmaLinux or Rocky Linux I am still getting a debranded RHEL clone, is that accurate? Other than comfort my reason for wanting to stay in the RHEL-verse is kABI tracking.

Can anyone provide some insight to this?